# Necessary condition for a curve to provide a weak extremum(calculus of variation)

Tags: calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

Necessary condition for a curve to provide a weak extremum.

Let $x(t)$ be the extremum curve.

Let $x=x(t,u) = x(t) + u\eta(t)$ be the curve with variation in the neighbourhood of $(\varepsilon,\varepsilon')$.

Let $I(u) = \int^b_aL(t,x(t,u),\dot{x}(t,u))dt = \int^b_aL(t,x(t) + u\eta(t),\dot{x}(t) + u\dot{\eta}(t))dt$

> Taylor’s theorem indicates that, for $u$ sufficiently small, $I(u)$ can be
> represented by
> $$I(u) = I(0) +  u \left(\frac{\textrm{d}I}{\textrm{d}u}\right)_{u=0} + O(u^2)$$

My question 1 is: Why does $u$ need to be small to represent the Taylor expansion of $I(u)$? doesn't the Taylor series work for any size $u$?

> Suppose the curve $x(t,u) = x(t) + u\eta(t)$ yeild a minimum value. Then because the curve  is in the neighbourhood of $(\varepsilon,\varepsilon')$, the condition $u \left(\frac{\textrm{d}I}{\textrm{d}u}\right)_{u=0} = 0$ must necessarily hold as a result of the talyor expansion (above)

My question 2 is: why must it hold as a result of the talyor expansion? shouldn't $ \left(\frac{\textrm{d}I}{\textrm{d}u}\right)_{u=0} = 0$ just in general hold as $I(u)$ has a extremum when $u=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me just work in the scalar case of some function $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ which has a local extremum at $0$.

1. The Taylor expansion $f(u) = f(0) + u f'(0) + O(u^2)$ only holds for small enough $u$. First, it is only interesting for small $u$ (when $u$ is large, the $O(u^2)$ term is very large and so cannot be interpreted as an "error" term). Second, it is wrong as $u \to +\infty$. For example, take $f(u) := u^4$. Then you obviously don't have $f(u) = O(u^2)$ as $u \to +\infty$.
2. How do you prove that $f'(0) = 0$ when $0$ is a local extremum? Most proofs I know indeed use the Taylor expansion to prove this fact. I believe this is why your text mentions it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Are we letting $O(u^2)\rightarrow 0$ for our $u$ being small? I am a bit lost with the Taylor method of proving local extremum, could you link a proof to this?

Comment: So. Assume $f$ has a local minimum (say) at $u=0$. Write $f(u) = f(0) + u f'(0) + O(u^2)$. This means that there exists $U, C > 0$ such that, for every $u \in [-U,U]$, $|f(u)-f(0)-uf'(0)| \leq C u^2$. Assume by contradiction that $f'(0) \neq 0$, say $f'(0) > 0$. Then, for $u$ small enough $C|u| < |f'(0)|/2$. Hence for $0<u$ small enough, $f(u) \geq f(0) + u f'(0)/2 > f(0)$. And similarly you cannot have $f'(0) < 0$.