# Proof that $f′(0)=0$ when $x=0$ is a local extremum(taylor method)

Tags: real-analysis

I am working with the proof that $f′(0)=0$  when $x= 0$  is a local extremum, for the taylor method (I understand the Fermat's theorem)
I was given an answer this question on [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4682881/necessary-condition-for-a-curve-to-provide-a-weak-extremumcalculus-of-variation)

> Assume $f$ has a local minimum (say) at $u=0$. Write $f(u)=f(0)+uf′(0)+O(u^2)$. This means that there exists $U,C>0$ such that, for every $u∈[−U,U]$, $|f(u)−f(0)−uf′(0)|≤Cu^2$. Assume by contradiction that $f′(0)≠0$, say $f′(0)>0$. Then, for $u$ small enough $C|u|<|f′(0)|/2$. Hence for $0<u$ small enough, $f(u)≥f(0)+uf′(0)/2>f(0)$. And similarly you cannot have $f′(0)<0$

But after playing around with it I still can't understand it. I wanted to open a new question instead of running the comment section.

$\textbf{The part I think I understand}:$

I understand $u∈[−U,U]$, $|f(u)−f(0)−uf′(0)|≤Cu^2$, where I am guessing that $C$ is chosen so that $C \geq \frac{f''(u)}{2}$ for all $u \in [−U,U]$ hence $Cu^2 \geq \frac{f''(\epsilon)}{2}u^2 = O(u^2)$. Thus $|f(u)−f(0)−uf′(0)| = O(u^2) ≤Cu^2$

Then we can get $C|u|<|f'(0)|/2$, by: for some $u$, and as $f'(0)$ is a constant(not dependent on $u$), $C|u|=|f'(0)|/4 < |f'(0)|/2$

$\textbf{the part I can't figure out}:$

How do you get: $f(u)≥f(0)+uf′(0)/2$ ?

and then how do you get: $f(0)+uf′(0)/2>f(0)$?

I feel like this is incorrect,my counter example: if $u<0$ then because $f′(0)/2 > 0$ thus $uf′(0)/2 < 0$, hense $f(0)+uf′(0)/2<f(0)$

Comment: You have to add more restrictions to $f$ because $f(x)=\lvert x\rvert$ has a local minimum at $x=0$ but the derivative doesn't exist at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the quoted comment is mine, let me expand the proof a little bit. (You could have asked for clarifications under the comment, I would have done so there).

First, of course, as recalled by @john-douma, you of course have to assume sufficient regularity on $f$ (in [my initial answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4682892/148248), I had assumed $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ by simplicity, but $C^1$ is of course sufficient).

So we assumed that $f$ had a local minimum at $0$, and that, by contradiction $f'(0) > 0$.
So it seems that you understand everything up to the point where we know that, for $u$ small enough: $C|u| \leq \frac{f'(0)}{2}$ and $|f(u) - f(0) - u f'(0)| \leq Cu^2$.

Combining both inequalities, you get, **for $u > 0$** small enough, $|f(u) - f(0) - u f'(0)| \leq \frac{f'(0)}{2} u$. This is of the form $|a-b| \leq c$. So $a \geq b - c$, that is $$f(u) \geq f(0) + u f'(0) - \frac{f'(0)}{2} u = f(0) + u \frac{f'(0)}{2}.$$
Since $f'(0) > 0$ and $u > 0$, the right-hand side is $> f(0)$.

Note that, both in [my initial comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4682881/necessary-condition-for-a-curve-to-provide-a-weak-extremumcalculus-of-variation#comment9903316_4682892) and here, you indeed take positive values of $u$ at some point in the argument. This avoids the "counterexample" you are talking about.

Similarly, you can also prove that it cannot happen that $f'(0) < 0$, this time by taking some small $u < 0$.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. Doesn't proving $f(u)>f(0)$ support the fact of a minimum?
\
I went ahead to add:

Letting $C|u| \leq \frac{f'(0)}{2}$, thus $-\frac{f'(0)}{2}\leq Cu \leq \frac{f'(0)}{2}$.
\
Letting $u<0$, thus $-u\frac{f'(0)}{2}\geq Cu^2 \geq \frac{f'(0)}{2}u$.
\
Now as $|f(u) -f(0) - uf'(0)|\leq Cu^2$, thus $-Cu^2\leq f(u) -f(0) - uf'(0)\leq Cu^2$. Taking $f(u)\leq f(0) + uf'(0)+Cu^2$. and $Cu^2\leq-u\frac{f'(0)}{2}$ we get:
\
$f(u)\leq f(0) + uf'(0)+Cu^2\leq f(0) + u\frac{f'(0)}{2}< f(0)$
\
Thus as we can't get $f(u)\geq f(0)$ for all $u\in[-U,U]$, f(0) can't be minimum.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Do you think something is wrong with by proof? Are you trying to handle another case?

Comment: sorry I ran out of characters, I wanted to say that proving $f(u) > f(0)$ does not contradict the idea that if $f'(0) > 0$ then $f(0)$ is not minimum. Or am I not understanding it? I continued the proof for the other side $u<0$ with again $f'(0) > 0$, and found that $f(u)< f(0)$. Then this contradics the idea that $f(0)$ is a minimum, making $f'(0) \leq 0$ and I guess by assume $f'(0) < 0$ then we will get  $f'(0) \geq 0$ thus must have $f'(0) = 0$?

Comment: Exactly. Indeed, I went on the wrong side!

Comment: Thank you your help, and super fast replies. I was stuck on this for a while.